# Lazy Load function broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this lazy loading function. On execution it first loads a small version of the image and later loads the full version. I needed this to quickly give the user a working slideshow before starting to load the really big images.

It all worked before I added in the last if statement:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass('lazyLoaded'))
```

And the mutations to the class after loading each image:

```
$(this).addClass('lazyLoaded');
```

I want to check if the images had been loaded before. I need this, because else on a next execution, the script would replace the full sized images with the smaller images and then later reloading the large images.

**When I add this extra if statement and the 2 .addClass operations, the script stops working. I have no clue why, can you help me?**

A weird side-effect I also noticed is the counting of the image length was 1 too high.

html:

```
<img src="img/3x2.gif" data-src="img/photo/event.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="img/3x2.gif" data-src="img/photo/wedding.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="img/3x2.gif" data-src="img/photo/portrait.jpg" alt="" />
```

jQuery:

```
     $.fn.lazyLoad = function(){
        if($(this).is('img[data-src]')) {
            var lazy = $(this);
        } else {
            var lazy = $(this).find('img[data-src]');
        };
        var lazyLength = $(lazy).length;
        console.log('lazyLength = ' + lazyLength);
        var lazyNumber = 0
        $(lazy).each(function(){
            if (!$(this).hasClass('lazyLoaded')) {
                if (loadTime > 300) {
                    var src = $(this).data('src');
                    var srcPath = src.slice(0, -4);
                    var srcExt =    src.slice(-4);
                    var srcNew = srcPath + '_s' + srcExt;
                    $(this).one('load', function(){
                        lazyNumber++;
                        console.log('lazyNumber = ' + lazyNumber);                      
                        if (lazyNumber >= lazyLength) {
                            console.log('all small images have been loaded');
                            console.log('setting Timeout for 500ms');
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                console.log('beginning loading of large images...');
                                $(lazy).each(function(){
                                    $(this).one('load', function(){
                                        console.log('large images loaded');
                                        $(this).addClass('lazyLoaded');
                                    }).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
                                });
                            }, 500);
                        };
                    }).attr('src', srcNew);
                    console.log('small image loaded');
                } else {
                    $(this).one('load', function(){
                        $(this).addClass('lazyLoaded');
                        console.log('large images loaded immediately');
                    }).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
                };
            };
        });
    };
```

Comment: I don't see your `loadTime` defined anywhere

Comment: Side note, within $.fn `this` is already a jQuery object

Comment: Not sure if it is your issue, but why are you binding to 'load' twice?

Comment: can you check you check your console, what do you get there(any error)?

Comment: There are no errors thrown. LoadTime is defined by window

Comment: ... There are no errors thrown. LoadTime is defined by window.performance before this function. I run .one('load') twice because I load 2 images for each object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error was created by adding the if statement within the *.each* loop. When I thought about it, it was not the most efficient way either.

I just have to test the images for both having a *data-src* attribute and not being loaded already (thus having the class *'.lazyLoaded'*, before passing them to the *var lazy* array.

So I still add the *'.lazyLoaded'* class on load of the large image

```
$(this).one('load', function(){
  console.log('large images loaded');
  $(this).addClass('lazyLoaded');
}).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
```

And in the beginning of the function I added *.not('.lazyLoaded')*

```
if($(this).is('img[data-src]')) {
  var lazy = $(this).not('.lazyLoaded');
} else {
  var lazy = $(this).find('img[data-src]').not('.lazyLoaded');
};
```

Just posting the entire working code, maybe it is of use to someone with a similar problem:

```
$.fn.lazyLoad = function(){
    if($(this).is('img[data-src]')) {
        var lazy = $(this).not('.lazyLoaded');
    } else {
        var lazy = $(this).find('img[data-src]').not('.lazyLoaded');
    };
    var lazyLength = $(lazy).length;
    console.log('lazyLength = ' + lazyLength);
    var lazyNumber = 0
    console.log('lazyNumber = ' + lazyNumber);
    $(lazy).each(function(){
            if (loadTime > 300) {
                var src = $(this).data('src');
                var srcPath = src.slice(0, -4);
                var srcExt = src.slice(-4);
                var srcNew = srcPath + '_s' + srcExt;
                $(this).one('load', function(){
                    lazyNumber++;
                    console.log('lazyNumber = ' + lazyNumber);                      
                    if (lazyNumber >= lazyLength) {
                        console.log('all small images have been loaded');
                        console.log('setting Timeout for 500ms');
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            console.log('beginning loading of large imags...');
                            $(lazy).each(function(){
                                $(this).one('load', function(){
                                    console.log('large images loaded');
                                    $(this).addClass('lazyLoaded');
                                }).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
                            });
                        }, 500);
                    };
                }).attr('src', srcNew);
                console.log('small image loaded');
            } else {
                $(this).one('load', function(){
                    console.log('large images loaded immediately');
                    $(this).addClass('lazyLoaded');
                }).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
            };
    });
};
$('.lazy').lazyLoad();
```